# Change globally scoped variable in JavaScript from inside a function

Tags: javascript, scope

I am having some trouble with changing globally scoped variables through a nested function call.

I am trying to create a script that calls itself every 5 seconds. On the first run it should take the globally scoped variable 'a' and change it. This change is intended to stick so that when the script runs a second time the global variable 'a' is forever changed.

For some reason, this isn' the case though. I have learned about var, const, let and hoisting, but coming from python, I feel my logic is maybe biased?

```js
var a = 'test';

var test_function = function(obj) {
  console.log("This is the first 'a':" + " " + obj);

  if (a == obj) {
    console.log(" This is the win state, our global variable changed on the second run!")

  } else {
    var a = "The 'a' changed";
    console.log("Inner circle: Now our a is:" + " " + a);
  }
  console.log("Second circle: Our 'a' is still:" + " " + a);
  console.log('_________________NEXT_______________')
  return a;
};

//Calls the test_function
function run_interval(obj) {
  test_function(obj)
};

//Defined the interval that is run every 5 sec
setInterval(function() {
  run_interval(a);
}, 5000);
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of `var` in the function. That makes it a local variable instead of updating the global variable.

Comment: You'll never go to the `else` block, because you call `run_interval(a)`, so `obj` is always the same as `a`. So you never change `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare `var a` inside the function. That makes it a local variable instead of updating the global variable.

Just assign the variable without the `var` declaration.

```js
var a = 'test';

var test_function = function(obj) {
  console.log("This is the first 'a':" + " " + obj);

  if (a == obj) {
    console.log(" This is the win state, our global variable changed on the second run!")

  } else {
    a = "The 'a' changed";
    console.log("Inner circle: Now our a is:" + " " + a);
  }
  console.log("Second circle: Our 'a' is still:" + " " + a);
  console.log('_________________NEXT_______________')
  return a;
};

//Calls the test_function
function run_interval(obj) {
  test_function(obj)
};

//Defined the interval that is run every 5 sec
setInterval(function() {
  run_interval(a);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
else {
    var a = "The 'a' changed";
     console.log("Inner circle: Now our a is:" + " " + a);
}
```

Notice how you again declared the variable as 'var'. This made 'a' in else part a local variable. Remove that var.